# How to store data from Bigquery to cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How can I store the data from big query to cloud storage?

This is my data and the threshold value that I set for the data.

```
SELECT milliVolt FROM `zeta-pivot` 
where milliVolt < 3300
limit 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
uri='gs://your file location.csv',
format='csv',
overwrite=true,
header=true,
field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT milliVolt FROM `the place that data save in bigquery` 
order by time desc
limit 100
```

This is how I use the way to save the data to the cloud storage.